# Cannot install sf package on Ubuntu server fails due to malloc error

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm trying to install the latest sf package (version 0.9-4) using R 4.0 on an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 18.04. I get this error:

```
testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
malloc_consolidate(): invalid chunk size
Aborted (core dumped)
ERROR: loading failed
```

I've tried downloading the package several ways, and I can download other packages just fine. There are 15G of ram available and 47G of available space on the hard drive. I can't figure out how this would be a memory problem or what my next steps might be.

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to install it, although I'm not sure what exactly fixed it. It may have been updating various dependencies.